# RTK Query - Update existing data (streaming with websocket)

Tags: redux, rtk-query

i have another problem while using RTK Query.
We initially fetch data with a get request. Once the result added to the cache, we want add the websocket connection and listen for any changes.
But the only thing i can find in the docs is, just adding further entries via `.push`.

But we have to update already existing data.

The structure of the data is:

```
[
   {
      resources: event.resources, // Array
      events: event.events, // Array
      resourceTimeRanges: event.resourceTimeRanges, // Array
      calendars: event.calendars,  // Array
      project: event.project, // Array
              },
];
```

Via websocket we get changes only for the events prop of the object.
So we have to update an entry in the events array.
How would it looks like?

Our code:

```
async onCacheEntryAdded(arg, { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved }) {
        const state = store.getState();
        const currentUser = state.user.uuid;
        console.log(currentUser);

        try {
          // wait for the initial query to resolve before proceeding
          await cacheDataLoaded;

          // when data is received from the socket connection to the server,
          // if it is a message and for the appropriate channel,
          // update our query result with the received message
          const listener = (event) => {
            schedulerData.util.updateData('getSchedulerEvents', undefined, (draft) => {
              // Test data              
              const newEvent = { id: 2, name: 'newName' };

              // How do i update data here???
            });

            updateCachedData((draft) => {
              console.log(draft);
            });
          };
          // client-side
          socketClient.emit('schedulerRoom', 'join');
          socketClient.on('scheduler', (payload) => {
            console.log('Joined room!');
            console.log(payload);
            listener(payload);
          });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
          // no-op in case `cacheEntryRemoved` resolves before `cacheDataLoaded`,
          // in which case `cacheDataLoaded` will throw
        }
        // cacheEntryRemoved will resolve when the cache subscription is no longer active
        await cacheEntryRemoved;
        // perform cleanup steps once the `cacheEntryRemoved` promise resolves
      },
```

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a websocket example in their [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/streaming-updates)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you need to use

```
updateCachedData((draft) => {
  console.log(draft);
});
```

inside your event listener.